# Returning info from Listener in Swing App

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

Hi i have `MainFrame` class:

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame{

    private JLabel originalLabel;
    private JLabel filteredImage;

    public MainFrame(){
        setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        initComponents();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void initComponents(){
        ImageFilterMenuBar menuBar = new ImageFilterMenuBar();

        originalLabel = new JLabel("Test1");
        filteredImage = new JLabel("Test2");

        Component verticalStrut = Box.createVerticalStrut(10);

        JPanel central = new JPanel();
        central.add(originalLabel);
        central.add(verticalStrut);
        central.add(filteredImage);


        add(new RadioButtonsPanel(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        add(central, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    }

}
```

and `MenuBar` class:

```
public class ImageFilterMenuBar extends JMenuBar{

    private JMenu fileMenu;
    private JMenuItem openImage;
    private JMenuItem exit;


    public ImageFilterMenuBar(){
        initCompoments();
    }

    private void initCompoments() {
        fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        setMenuItems();
        add(fileMenu);
    }

    private void setMenuItems(){
        openImage = new JMenuItem("Open Image");
        exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");

        openImage.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_O,
                InputEvent.CTRL_MASK));

        exit.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_CANCEL,InputEvent.SHIFT_MASK));

        openImage.addActionListener(new OpenListener());
        exit.addActionListener(new ExiteListener());

        fileMenu.add(openImage);
        fileMenu.add(exit);
    }

}
```

in MenuBar class you can sea OpenButton. it's open JFileChooser and returns me url of file which I chose.
So now I don't know how to send this url into my MainFrame class where I want to display this file..
Any ideas??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest solution is to pass a reference to `MainFrame` to the `ImageFilterMenuBar`:

```
ImageFilterMenuBar menuBar = new ImageFilterMenuBar(this);
```

Then, add a method like below in the MainFrame:

```
public void setImageFile(File file) {
  // do whatever here
}
```

In the `ImageFilterMenuBar` you would keep a reference to the `MainFrame` in a member variable and use it to call `setImageFile()` once the `JFileChooser` returns a File.

A more difficult to implement solution would be to implement the observer pattern. This is the way the listeners work in Swing.
You would register the main frame as a listener and the other class would be the one to notify about file selection changes.

To open a file chooser and get the selected file:

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser(path);
int result = chooser.showOpenDialog(mainFrame);
File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION && file != null && file.exists()) {
  mainFrame.setImageFile(file);
}
```

Comment: how ImageFilterMenuBar class know that filechooser choose file?

Comment: See my edited answer. If you have more questions, please ask them separately.

Answer (score 2):

Do not extend menu-bar or frame, simply keep references to them in the same app. ..

I was about to add *"that has an URL class attribute."* but it is not clear how you are using the URL.  If it is for a `JEditorPane` I might declare the instance of it in place of the URL attribute, and just set the page directly on selection in the listener.

Comment: I write my question incorect. I send url of image. And than display it. It's is my first experiance in SWING so may be I make something wrong or structure of progect is incorrect... so If you have advices you are welcome)). May be you know any good examples in internet? All information will be helpfull